# What is happening when a pop-up comes up and disappears immediatly

Tags: macos, firefox, popups

Sometimes when I visit a (file-sharing) site a pop-up shows up that immediately closes afterwards.
It's there for only a split second. It doesn't seem as if a site is actually loaded in the pop-up, then again it disappears very quickly so I can't tell.

Can this do any harm?

I am not linking to the actual site in case the pop-up is harmful in a way.

I'm on Mountain Lion 10.8.5 with Firefox 27.0.1.

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker installed?

Comment: Yes, AdBlock Plus 2.5.1

Comment: Ad blockers may take a split second to detect and kill a popup, so you'll still see the window appear briefly in such cases.

Comment: It's not only ad blockers. You can also experience the same thing with the default pop-up blocker in FF, especially if the site you are visiting is heavy with scripts.

Comment: So chances are low that it's some malicious script executing very fast or something?